# hook_menu_alter() inconsistent response

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

This snippet of code responds for user#1 but not for other logged in or anonymous users:

```
function module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items["node/add/page"]['access callback'] = 'module_access_callback';
}

function module_access_callback(){    
  die('responding here - test');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: double check permission for logged in users and anonymous users Maybe they don't have access for 'node/add/page'

Comment: I have 'access content' permission set for anonymous and authenticated users. I can't imagine anything else that would require setting. ???

Comment: @sisko: I'm just going to try your code myself as I suspect it will work and that there are other forces (namely some sort of node access module) causing the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the code you are really using, then the access callback function is wrong, as it should return `TRUE` when the currently logged-in user has access to the menu, and `FALSE` when the user doesn't have access to the menu. It doesn't use `die()`.

This is what reported in the documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7):

> "access callback": A function returning `TRUE` if the user has access rights to this menu item, and `FALSE` if not. It can also be a boolean constant instead of a function, and you can also use numeric values (will be cast to boolean). Defaults to [user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/7) unless a value is inherited from the parent menu item; only [MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/7) items can inherit access callbacks. To use the `user_access()` default callback, you must specify the permission to check as 'access arguments'.

If you are not showing the code you are using, then what follows can explain the behavior you are seeing.
The first user, or user #1, is a particular user because [user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/7) always return `TRUE` for that user.
This is evident in the code of that function, which explicitly check the user ID is equal to 1.

```
// User #1 has all privileges:
if ($account->uid == 1) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

If the access callback returns `FALSE` for authenthicated users, and it is using `user_access()`, it is because the authenticated users don't have the permission passed to the function.

It could also be you are checking for more than one permission, and you are using `user_access('first permission') && user_access('second permission')`, instead of `user_access('first permission') || user_access('second permission')` (or vice versa). For the user #1 that doesn't make any difference, as the result of `user_access('first permission') && user_access('second permission')` and `user_access('first permission') || user_access('second permission')` is always `TRUE`, even if you pass to the function a string for a permission that is not defined from any module.

Comment: Assuming you are right and it is a permission issue, my authenticated users already have the ability to edit the specific node-type. Unless there is a way to determine the permission creating the problem, is there a way to bypass user_access in a single section of my module?

Comment: When you define an access callback, the user gets access to that menu basing on what returned from that function, which could not even use `user_access()`. I cannot say anything more, as you are not showing the code used for your access callback. (The shown code is just test code.)

Comment: The code is essentially What I am attempting to do. It just is not responding if you happen not to be UID#1.

Comment: An access callback doesn't call `die()`; it just returns `TRUE` when the user has access to the menu, and `FALSE` when it doesn't have access.

Comment: Yeah but die() is just php code. If it works for one user it should work for another. The question is what might be stopping it for other users and how to prevent it

Comment: It doesn't matter why it happens in one case, and not in the other; you should not call `die()` in an access callback, and in many other callback used by Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

OK It turns out the answer is actually very simple...

You're calling `menu_get_object()` to retrieve the node, but no node exists on `node/add/page`. In fact quite the opposite; it wouldn't make sense to have a node available on the page to add a node, as it hasn't been created yet! The 403 is a side effect of this.

You'll need to make your access decision based on some other value (normally the logged in user along with a permission as @kiamlaluno has done a very good job of explaining in his answer).

Also do make sure you return `TRUE` or `FALSE` from your access callback as @kiamlaluno has also stated :)

**EDIT**

Just to say that this is partially an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342169/drupal-hook-menu-alter-menu-get-object-error, which explains why there are functions mentioned in this answer that aren't mentioned in the question.